# Why is the site running in IE quirks mode?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, byte-order-mark, browser-bugs

I've got a site: http://www.sucramma.dk
When I'm in FF, Chrome, or Safari, the site is displayed as it should, but in IE the site is left aligned, and is running is quirks mode. Why? The doctype is set!

Comment: How do you know it's in quirks mode?

Comment: IE doesn't have a mode called "quirks mode". Do you mean to say "compatibility view"? IE 9 RC doesn't say it's rendering your site in compatibility view.

Comment: @In silico: He means this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode

Comment: @Eineki: I know what the OP meant. I was saying that IE doesn't have something that is called "quirks mode," but is rather called "compatibility view".

Comment: @Insilico yes, IE [has quirks mode](http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/302/iequirks.png).

Comment: It's probably a bit late, but... what version(s) of IE were being tested here that resulted in the BOM triggering quirks mode?

Comment: The question has become meaningless, as the content was specified by URL only, and the content has apparently changed to something completely different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

It's a Byte Order Mark, , which is invisible to most text editors. Try using VIM and killing it or somehow find a different text editor and kill everything before `<!DOCTYPE html>`

You can simply copy `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` and everything below it into a new file and save over it, meaning you wont be copying the BOM coming before it to resolve this issue; I've ran into it many times.

Comment: Re your first edit, yeah, Eineki ran it through the validator and found something.

Comment: There is no whitespace before the doctype, i've checked in 3 different editors, and cant delete any white space :(

Comment: Use VIM and you'll see something. It has to do with BOM.

Comment: @nick how did you upload the file to the server? How you make changes?

Comment: I had an itching feeling it was the BOM... indeed it is :)

Comment: The analysis is incorrect. There is something else than the BOM at the start, apparently a line break. Then U+FEFF isn’t a BOM any more.

Comment: The validator error message quoted in @Eineki’s answer proves that it was not the BOM. The validator has always accepted the BOM (which is valid). So is a line break, but line break + U+FEFF is something completely different.

Answer (score 5):

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.sucramma.dk&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

The validation fails, see the first error:

Error Line 1, Column 1: Non-space characters found without seeing a doctype first. Expected .

The doctype is not sufficient to oblige the browser to standard mode. When an error it is encountered the rendering fall back to quirks mode.

Correct the errors and try again, you should be done

Comment: Very very nice, I don't think anyone else but the validator could've spotted that mysterious character. +1

Comment: Yeah, but the strange thing is that there is no characters set before the doctype, not whitespace either :S - Dont know why the validation is saying this

Comment: @nickycdk - use vim to make the edit or copy everything starting with `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` and make new file and resave it.

Comment: @nickycdk: It is the [bom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), usally the editors ignore it and don't show it. It is a well known, to me, utf-8 plague

Comment: It is not possible any more to analyze what the problem page contained, but probably it started with a line break and the U+FEFF character. At least such a combination triggers the error message mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The site doesn't have a DOCTYPE so it will be running in quirks mode because it doesn't know what DTD to use...

EDIT: As pointed out by BoltClock, it does have a DOCTYPE (I'm just not up to scratch on HTML5 yet). My apologies.

Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: Uh, it does have a doctype. Visit the site, and view the source.

Comment: @Bolt as far as I know `<!DOCTYPE html>` is not valid.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: It's the HTML5 doctype, and I believe IE recognizes it as a doctype.

Comment: @BoltClock Yeah, that's me not being up to speed on HTML5, doh!

Comment: IE should be able to recognize the html5 doctype

Answer (score 0):

Try using full doctype declaration (and without a space at the beginning)

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` is the HTML5 doctype declaration and is valid.

Comment: Cant use this, im running html5

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue I changed to `<!DOCTYPE html>` and the it fixed it