# Does PHP or Apache affect DTD: Problem with rendering XHTML in IE7 standard mode

Tags: php, apache, xhtml, unicode, byte-order-mark

I have a static HTML(index.html) with DOCTYPE below which will trigger the standard mode in IE7:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
```

I then transform the page into three PHP HTML templates:header.html.php, index.php, footer.html.php. And the header.html.php includes the exact DOCTYPE as above.

But every time I claim the index.php in IE7, it messes up the rendering.

I have used the command `javascript:alert(document.compatMode)` to test in IE7 and FF3

For the static html page, both IE7 and FF3 give me CSS1Compat, which is the mode I expected;
But for the PHP generated page, FF3 give me CSS1Compat while IE7 give me BackCompat.

**Here is something I think the problem lies:**
I have downloaded the page from IE7 and found the DOCTYPE become `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">` without the address.

But downloading the same PHP generated page in ff3 and chrome, the DOCTYPE is correctly `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

When I test the page, not surprisingly, the very first lines the source code the W3C validator get is `# <!-- A customized tag to distinguish different pages --> # <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

And a W3C validation indicates the empty first line.

I have removed the BOM on **all** the static PHP files and CSS files but I still get the problem.

Is this a problem with Apache or PHP? Anyone have a clue to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post something from your header.html.php file so we can see if there is something near the beginning that's causing this fail? Also, what happens when you run the javascript for the php generated page in a webkit browser? The only reason that could be of interest is because FF3 and IE7 currently give you different results...

Comment: @jlmcdonald here is the full content of the header.html.php and the javascript result in chrome is the same as FF3. `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <!-- Make IE8 works in IE7 standard mode -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7;FF=3;OtherUA=4" />
  <title><?php echo "$title"; ?></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/reset.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/960.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css" />
 </head>
<body>`

Comment: One possibility could be that the php files have some hidden byte order marks that don't show up as whitespace or anything else ... but that BOM will throw IE7 into quirks mode. See this question which offers a solution. It may not be your problem, but it could help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063789/why-is-the-site-running-in-ie-quirks-mode

Comment: Another interesting observation is that when downloading the same PHP generated page in ff3 and chrome, the DOCTYPE is correct `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

Comment: @jlmcdonald I have used Vim to check the BOM and it is clear before <!DOCTYPE...

Comment: Try running your URL (from the generated PHP, not the static HTML) through the W3C validator (http://validator.w3.org/) ... does it come back clean? Another thing to look at might be the encoding of the php ... are they UTF-8? ISO-8859-1? etc.

Comment: @jlmcdonald I test the page, not surprisingly, the very first lines the source code the validator get is `# <!-- A customized tag to distinguish different pages -->
# <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`  Is it added by PHP or server?

Comment: It's probably added by whatever process is stitching your three sections together ... almost undoubtedly by PHP (it would take some work to get the server to put in comments like that ... you'd have to have some sort of middleware system). Is this a content management system?

Answer (score 2):

One thing to look into is the character encoding your response is returning. If the character encoding is other than the default (UTF-8 or -16), then you're supposed to include an xml declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html 
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Because you're getting the appropriate content back in other browsers, I suspect there's something causing IE choke and so it's changing it to a more laxed doctype.

Have you validated the document using the W3C validator?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not an apache or php problem. It is a problem of the code, that generates the response.

Comment: I bet so, but whatever doctype change I give to the PHP header.html.php file, IE7 still renders it in quirk mode. And the file I downloaded form IE7 lacks of the dd address. It's why IE didn't get the doctype.

Comment: @Steven: if there is no doctype url in response - then you have not specified it in scripts.

Comment: I have written it in my header.html.php and firefox has already got it.

Comment: @Steven: If you have done that - then it should be in a response for **every** browser. There is no miracles in programming.

Comment: (and @Steven indirectly): That's not quite true; see my comment above concerning byte order marks. If there is one present before the doctype, then IE will read it and put its own doctype in place (putting it into quirks mode), while other browsers ignore the BOM and accept the given doctype.