# div width auto !important seems not to work in ie6/ie7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, width

THE HTML

```
<div class="grid_11 omega" id="homeGalleryFichaGold">
        <div class="contSlideGalleryUp" style="display: none;"> 
                                    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#panelGallery').slideToggle(); $('.contSlideGalleryUp').hide(); $('.contSlideGalleryDown').slideToggle('slow');" id="openGallery" class="openGallery" title="">HOTEL GALLERY</a>
        </div>
        <div style="display: block;" class="contSlideGalleryDown"> 
                                    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#panelGallery').slideToggle(); $('.contSlideGalleryUp').slideToggle('slow'); $('.contSlideGalleryDown').hide();" id="closeGallery" class="closeGallery" title="">HOTEL GALLERY</a>
                                </div>                        
                                <div style="display: block;" id="panelGallery">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="selected"><a class="photos" href="#" title=""><span>PHOTOS</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a class="videos" href="#" title=""><span>VIDEOS</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a class="suites" href="#" title=""><span>SUITES 3D</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a class="location" href="#" title=""><span>LOCATION</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a class="publication" href="#" title=""><span>PUBLICATION</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a class="tour" href="#" title=""><span>INTERACTIVE TOUR</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a class="panorama" href="#" title=""><span>PANORAMA</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a class="googlearth" href="#" title=""><span>GOOGLE EARTH</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
          </div>                                       
    </div>
```

Basically i can't get #panelGallery to have an 'auto' width in IE6/7 (works fine in all other)

CSS

```
    #panelGallery {
        background-color: #333;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        float: right;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: bold;
        height: 65px;
        line-height: 65px;
        opacity: 0.9;
        /*width: 640px;*/
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        right:0px;  
    }
    .contSlideGalleryDown {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 65px;
    right:0;
}
```

And i add this hack for ie6/7

```
#panelGallery {
    *width: auto !important;
}
```

But still uses all width

Answer (score 1):

It looks like IE uses Quirks Mode, because I'm sure that IE6/IE7 have support for `width:auto`. You can insert bookmarklet below to detect rendering mode.

```
javascript:alert(document.compatMode)
```

`CSS1Compat` means Standards Mode and `BackCompat` Quirks Mode.

If it shows `BackCompat` that means that IE seen something before `<!DOCTYPE>`. IE 6 and 7 uses Quirks Mode if it sees nearly anything before DOCTYPE, BOM mark or HTML comment counts into it.

There is already some question about it, so I will just link to it: [Why is the site running in IE quirks mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063789/why-is-the-site-running-in-ie-quirks-mode)

By the way, http://validator.nu/ can detect if site would trigger Quirks Mode in IE by using either comments or BOM mark.

Also, some `DOCTYPE`s can trigger Quirks Mode even if there is nothing before them can trigger Quirks Mode. http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/ contains list of those special `DOCTYPE`s.

Comment: i'm not sure if I understood: http://validator.nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.idiso.com%2Fextranet%2Fhm%2Fgen%2Ffichagold%2Fes%2Findex.html

Comment: The alert you suggested outputs: CSS1compat and there's nothing preceding doctype :S

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet: I was trying to guess problem. I don't know what might be actual problem... sadly...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the conditional statement rather than a star hack?

Something like:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<style>
#panelGallery {
   width: auto !important;
}

</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: true :) my mistake. Try zoom: 1, this often helps